# Place category Base URL at the end

Tags: categories, link-category

By default the Categories' URL will show like this: `example.com/category/category-name/`. In this case we say the category URL base is `category`.

Wordpress allow us to customize the URL base. For example: we can change it to `list` and our new category URL is going to be `example.com/list/category-name/`.

Nice.

I want to change the URL base to the end. So my URL category name now should be:
`example.com/category-name/list/`.

How can I achieve that goal?